# Having issues planning how many shards for elastic cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, ram, sharding

I am planning on storing data into an Elasticsearch cluster, and am having problems deciding how many shards to use. We are planning on housing data going back four years, and were wanting to divide each index per day, which would result in around 1460 indexes. As I understand it, you need as many shards as there are indexes. I have read that you should have one shard per 20-30GB of heap space, and heap space would be less than half the RAM. So am I accurate in assuming we would need somewhere around 30G * 1460shards = 43800G * 2 = 87.6TB RAM?!
This just doesn't sound right. Could someone clear up where I'm going wrong. I've done extensive googling, and even have talked to chat gpt about this lol.
If the above is accurate, I will gladly consolidate from daily indexes to something more realistic. I thought running an index with day-month-year was a common thing in elastic.

Comment: You need to start from the data volume. What is it like ?

Comment: Where have you read "one shard per 20-30GB of heap space"? It's "A good rule-of-thumb is to ensure you keep the number of shards per node below 20 per GB heap it has configured. A node with a 30GB heap should therefore have a maximum of 600 shards, but the further below this limit you can keep it the better".

Comment: Hey Riz, understood, thanks for the answer. I think I was confused before. Looks like I'd need to have around 73G heap to support 1460 indexes. Am I right in assuming I need as many shards as I have indexes? I was getting and error if I tried to create more indexes than shards.

Comment: @Val My indexes will have around 3G/day, so that's alot less than many people. But I do want to store the data going back four years, so it's 'alot' to retain.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not 30GB per shard but maybe it can be 30 shards per GB :)**

I'm sharing a couple of best practices, hope it helps.

> A good rule-of-thumb is to ensure you keep the number of shards per
> node below 20 per GB heap it has configured.

**Note: The rule of thumb on "Aim for 20 shards or fewer per GB of heap memory" has been deprecated in version 8.3. [This blog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#field-count-recommendation) has been updated to reflect the new recommendation.**
https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster

30G * 1460 shards * 2 (1 primary + 1 replica) = 87.6TB disk space you need.

According to your needs, you can keep indices on the different data tiers. For example, if you are frequently searching the last 24 hours you can decide to keep your shards on the hot node for 24 hours. After that with ILM policy, you can rollover the index and allocate the shards to the warm nodes.

**Hot tier:** more hardware resources and faster storage (SSDs)

**Warm or Cold tier:** middle hardware resources with HDD - don't use both of them, if there is no difference between warm and cold hardware

**Frozen tier:** Paid feature - Need a license to use searchable snapshots.

**Delete:** take the snapshot and delete
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-tiers.html

**Aim for shard sizes between 10GB and 50GB**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-size-recommendation

**Master-eligible nodes should have at least 1GB of heap per 3000 indices**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-count-recommendation

Please note that the recommendations are changing between the Elasticsearch versions like the example I shared above. Good luck!

Comment: and how much heap is the question ;-)